# Query count hashtag in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to query count post contains hashtag(#) where same hashtag(#) more than 1 in column.

Example :

tb_post

```
post_id | post
1       | #enjoy #go_green
2       | I like this #enjoy
3       | What about me? #enjoy #enjoy
4       | We have to back to nature #forlive #go_green #go_green
```

Is it possible to count #enjoy that should be 4 and #go_green 3?

Here is my query

```
SELECT SUBSTR( post, LOCATE( '#', post ) ) hashtag
FROM tb_post
WHERE post LIKE '%#enjoy%'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

When I execute that, it's only show 3. It should be 4.

Comment: Please see post_id no 3, it has 2 times #enjoy

Comment: Selecting a group of rows and doing frequency calculation on the application side will be easier to implement, will work faster and will be maintained with less issues/headaches.

Comment: You have to write an SP for your requirement, better use PHP variables and take the word count out of it.

Comment: @RocketSurgeon, OK I got it, how if in variable has 2 same hashtag? How can I get that 2 hashtag? Ex. I like this #verymuch #verymuch